# What would be the cost of doing an MS degree in US as Night classes especially for an full time employee?

Tags: masters, exams, degree, fees

Is there any Test or Test score required to get admission?

Is there any forum or website to understand more about night classes for MS degree in US?

Comment: There's no simple answer to this question. Prices will vary widely depending on the degree subject, the university, etc. Same for admission criteria. Some companies will pay some costs, particularly if the degree is job-related. Also, some places may not give all classes at night/weekend.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I understood to some extent

Comment: Your employer may offer educational support, such as tuition reimbursement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few universities have evening masters programs. They may not be top-tier universities and the programs are less likely to be research based. But they exist. You will need to investigate individual universities for costs, however, but expect several hundred dollars per course. There may also be a flat "matriculation fee" per semester. Multiply that by the number of required courses.

Most universities will publish their fee schedule on their website, so look at a few that seem interesting to you or those in your region.

The entry requirements for such programs may be lower than for residential (full-time) programs since it is easier to accommodate a variable number of students. An undergraduate degree from an accredited institution will be required, and test scores might be, though possibly not. Entry tests are becoming less of an issue. Letters of recommendation might be required as they are common in the US, but, again, not in all cases.

Look at a small sampling of universities to get an idea.

Note also that some places have week-end programs that allow you to spend all of one or two days per week in a program. This might be helpful to some, rather than night courses.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to reply to my query. I will certainly do some sampling and analysis of such universities